# Simple Rigid Body Simulation Animation not working

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am a complete Blender beginner and I have a problem with my simulation.

I have created a simple wrecking ball simulation that looks like this:[image: wrecking ball simulation]

However, I am trying to add more elements to this so I have tried adding another plane below the first one:
[image]

At this point, I have not enabled rigid body settings yet, so when I play the animation, the cubes fall through the plane:

[image]

Thus, once I turn rigid body settings on as such, I expect the cubes to fall on to the second plane instead of through it:[image]

However, this is what happens when I try to play the animation:
[image]

Comment: Tried clearing cache and baking again?

Comment: Could you provide your .blend file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you?

Comment: No idea, too little info on other rigid bodies, and can't easily replicate your setup, but shouldn't the second plane be set as "passive"?